# How to add custom message in chrome infobar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer, testim.io

I used to think that this was not possible but I recently saw that Testim has an extension that does this.

Core aim: Add a message in the page which doesn't interfere with the DOM/CSS of the existing page.

Chrome/Chromium injects "The browser is being automated" message in the page when the browser is run from puppeteer. But as I understood, this isn't an editable message. How is testim able to do this?

Here's a screenshot showing exact message: [image: image showing testim's custom message as chrome infobar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the message that is shown, when an Chrome extension [attaches to a tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#method-attach) via the [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API. It shows the name of the extension which is attached to the page, in your case the [Testim Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/testim-editor/pebeiooilphfmbohdbhbomomkkoghoia) extension.

**Removing the infobar**

To remove that bar, you have can either enable the "Silent Debugging" option in the Chrome flags (`chrome://flags`) manually or use the [`--silent-debugger-extension-api`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#silent-debugger-extension-api) flag when starting Chrome. There is no way to disable it programmatically from inside your extension.